# Resetting gemstash to original state

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Looking through the documentation, I have not found anything that resets the entire cache to the original state. 
I would like to delete all the gems that have been cached in gemstash.
I have tried deleting the `gem_cache` folder in gemstash, but when I rerun bundle install, nothing is populated in the `gem_cache` folder.
I have figured that it will only populate if all the files related to the gem is deleted in `.bundle/` folder. 
Is there an easier way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the files and folders in `gem_cache` is sufficient for resetting the cache. To repopulate the cache, make sure the file `Gemfile.lock` is deleted, to ensure that the dependencies are fetched from the source again. This means that it when fetching the dependencies, it would go through the gemstash, and therefore cached.